# Twilio sms have strange content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, twilio

Hey I just implemented Twilio sms solution in my rails app. I have several different questions about it :

1) I had to buy a german phone number to get access to sms service even though i live in France because apparently french phone number on twilio do not enable to send sms. Does anyone know about that ?

2) I manage to send sms through my app but, quite weirdly, the messages dont come from the german number I bought ! they come from what seem to be french numbers and they always come from a different number !

3)the content of the sms I receive is quite strange too it looks something like that: 4⁶!!⁴5‥‾†

my code looks like this:

```
def multiple_create
  @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
  @subscription_ids = params[:subscription_ids].split(', ')
  @subscription_ids.each do |subscription_id|
    @subscription = Subscription.find(subscription_id)
    convocation = Convocation.create(date: params[:date], hour: params[:hour], subscription: @subscription)
    if convocation.save
      flash[:alert] = "Votre convocation a bien été envoyé"


      client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

      # Create and send an SMS message
      client.account.sms.messages.create(
          from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
          to: convocation.subscription.user.telephone,
          body: "Vous êtes convoqué le  #{convocation.date}  à  #{convocation.hour} pour le tournoi #{convocation.subscription.tournament.name} %>"
      )
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Un problème est survenu veuillez réessayer d'envoyer votre convocation"
    end
  end
  redirect_to tournament_subscriptions_path(@tournament)
end
```

thanks everyone !

Comment: 2): they probably use a phone line closest to the type of number you want to send the text to reduce the fees. I am pretty sure they have few phones in few countries to do some load-balancing between each phone line. 3): Make sure the content you send is respecting Twilio's encoding (probably UTF-8 as seen in the docs)

Comment: Have you tried a SMS without any accent / special character to see if the content is ok?

Comment: thanks yes it was a problem with accent and it now works fine. My sms header is SMS. WOuld you know by any chance how to customize the sms header in twilio ? thanks again

Comment: No I don't, I've never used Twilio, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Hi Twilio Customer Support here:

1) I had to buy a german phone number to get access to sms service even though i live in France because apparently french phone number on twilio do not enable to send sms. Does anyone know about that ?

Unfortunately we do not have SMS capable local numbers in France at the moment

As for:

2) I manage to send sms through my app but, quite weirdly, the messages dont come from the german number I bought ! they come from what seem to be french numbers and they always come from a different number !

3)the content of the sms I receive is quite strange too it looks something like that: 4⁶!!⁴5‥‾†

Can you write into the helpdesk (help@twilio.com) with the [messageSIDs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance-properties) that display this issue and we will look into it.

Tom